# R Studio like editor for Python?

Tags: python, rstudio, software-recommendation

I hope this question is okay for the forum. I want to ask for your experiance with Python editors.

Currently, I use VS-Code to work with Python. However, in R Studio I really appreciate that it holds data frames in the memory and makes it easy to view/inspect dataframes and other items. I'm "closer to the data" in R Studio. Also line-by-line/blockwise execution of code is really helpful.

So my question: Is there anything like R Studio for Python (preferably non-browser based)? Can someone recommend an editor for Python with similar features like R Studio (especially wrt data handling)?

Answer (score 5):

Spyder is quite similar to R-studio.

Answer (score 1):

A less common option would be the IDE called [Rodeo](https://rodeo.yhat.com/). It was designed to mimic RStudio and may provide many of the features you are seeking. There is also something called [Reticulated Python](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/10/09/rstudio-1-2-preview-reticulated-python/) that allows you to use Python within Rstudio.

Answer (score 0):

For python development, three IDEs top most of the charts.

1. PyCharm
2. Spyder
3. Eclipse + PyDev

While second and third are open source, you can download the basic version of the first one for free. In all the three, you have option to enable a window too see the data you want to see while debugging.